# jQuery redirecting too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery redirection taking too slow to connect another page.  I have tried `window.location.replace`, `window.location.href`, `window.location`. Is there any way to make the redirect faster?

```
<form role="form" id="add_name"  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <div class="form-group modal-form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_id" name="email_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group modal-form">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" >
      </div>
      <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-popup"  name="submit" id="submit">save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script> 
  $("form#add_name").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: "device_process.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
        window.location = "thankyou.php";
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You are redirected when ajax returns a response. The slowness can be caused by your api being slow or you being on slow network

Comment: you are doing ajax and then refreshing why?

Comment: How about handling the wait in a different way. Perhaps display a spinner? Then redirect when the callback is done.

Comment: Not a problem with jquery. Read @cdoshi comment and add your redirecting code top of the submit funciton, you can see the immediate result.

Comment: use `console.log( window.performance.timing.navigationStart + window.performance.now())` just before your ajax success block.It will gives you idea about time taken by your API.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, sorry its not possible ,bcz i need to redirect the page after the  success message.

Comment: Redirection will happen only once the AJAX request is completed. Have you checked the time your AJAX requests take? Note the time of redirection with AJAX request and without AJAX request. That would give you a direction on where and whats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because your server side code may be taking some time to process the request. In such cases, it is better adding a progress loader to notify the user that their request is in progress. It is very easy to implement. Try the below codes. This will work. Hope this helps. Thanks

INSIDE BODY :

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none;"><div>Loading, Please wait...</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#loading {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    opacity: .9;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=90); 
    z-index: 99999;
    display: none;
}

#loading>div{
    position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -102px;
 width: 205px;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: left;
 background: url('../img/loading.gif') no-repeat; //add a loader image to your local
 margin-top: -30px;
 padding: 8px 0 0 35px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {

    $("#loading").fadeIn();

}).ajaxStop(function () {

    $("#loading").fadeOut();

    $(document).foundation();

});
```

Comment: was that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I have used jquery Timeout().function.

Here is my answer:

```
<script> 
$("form#add_name").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();   
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    url: "device_process.php", 
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
       //  window.location = "thankyou.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($devices); ?>";

    },
    cache: false,
  contentType: false, 
    processData: false,

});
timeout:2000 , 
window.location = "thankyou.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($devices);    ?>";
});
</script>
```